# Dynamic URL name with Angularjs and Ui-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working with AngularJs and Ui-Router in my webapp. I've come to a point where I want to make it more dynamic. This is the situation I'm facing:

- I have a list of cities;
- Each city has a list with a lot of business;

#### What i want is:

When i select the city "New York", for example, I'd like to set the `URL` to be: `mysite.com/#/new-york`
And when i access one business whitin the NewYork city, I'd like it to be something like: `mysite.com/#/new-york/name-business`

Currently I'm only passing the city `Id` so I get it as an URL param and then I get the business list based on this ID param.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
//City
.state('city', {
    url: "/City",
    views: {
        "main": {
            controller: 'CityCtrl',
            templateUrl: "content/section/city/city.html"
        }
    }
})

//Business
.state('business', {
    url: "/Business/:idparam",
    views: {
        "main": {
            controller: 'BusinessCtrl',
            templateUrl: "content/section/business/business.html"
        }
    }
})
```

Very simple. But instead of using the `URL` like `url: "/Cities"` I'd like it to be a dynamic url, based on the city name the user selects.

Is it possible to do it with `ui-router`? Because i didn't found anything about this in the docs.

If so, what should I do to achieve this result?

### Edit:

I'm trying the solution on the answer by @Anid Monsur but the param value in the URL is `0` even tought it's a name. For example: `site.com/#/0` instead of `site.com/#/city-name`

This is what i did:

```
.state('city', {
    abstract: true,
    url: "/:name",
    views: {
        "main": {
            controller: 'CityCtrl',
            templateUrl: "content/section/city/city.html"
        }
    }
})
```

And my link is:

```
ui-sref="city({name: {{city.nm_url}} })"
```

Any ideas why the value is 0?

### Edit2

Because i was passing a string value instead of int, i had to remove `{{ }}` from the link and it solved my issue = `ui-sref="city({name: city.nm_url })"`

Comment: just add another path segment and stateParam. Suggest you create url slugs for the names

Comment: I had tried this before, but i think it didn't worked because of the way the string was sent to the url. I don't know. Now I'm getting it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the easiest way to achieve your goal. Use child states so that each successive child appends segments to the url.

- The city state will have a blank url.
- Once a city is selected, the `city.business` state is active with a url of `/city` where `city` is a `$stateParam`, set to `new-york`, for example.
- After a business is selected, the `city.business.view` state is active with a url of `/city/business` where `city` is the same one as above, and `business` would be the business identifier.

State config:

```
//City list
.state('city', {
    url: "/",
    views: {
        "main": {
            controller: 'CityCtrl',
            templateUrl: "content/section/city/city.html"
        }
    }
})

//Business list for one city
.state('city.business', {
    url: "/:city",
    views: {
        "main": {
            controller: 'BusinessCtrl',
            templateUrl: "content/section/business/business.html"
        }
    }
})

// Specific Business
.state('city.business.view', {
    url: "/:business",
    views: {
        "main": {
            controller: 'BusinessCtrl',
            templateUrl: "content/section/business/business.html"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: My structure is a little different, but now I know how to proced in a better way! Thank you sr.